# Why is my SELECT query taking so long?

Tags: sql-server, select, sqlperformance

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notifications](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Fk_institutionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Fk_userId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Read] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[NotificationText] [text] NULL,
[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ReadDate] [datetime] NULL,
[DisplayDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ReadBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Notifications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

a simple `select * from Notifications` takes 30 seconds while there is only 800,000 rows in this table.

This actual situation is each  user performs the query `select * from notifications where DisplayDate is null and Fk_userId = [the user id]` and this create a server error in my .NET web application saying something about a deadlock.

The execution plan for that query is quite simple[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or why is it create a deadlock error?

Comment: it seems like there are more columns than listed above - as you CREATE statement isn't complete

Comment: may i know, why you want to select the whole table?
as far as i know SQL Server will perform a simple table scan.
involves scanning every single row of the table, allocating some memory, and returning it
that will be the fastest way to return te result

Comment: 30 seconds to fetch 800,000 rows is 26,667 rows per second. A slow network is 100Mbps or about 12.5 MB per second. So if your database records average about 500 bytes each (pretty easy if you have long text data), the network could be limiting your transfer speed.

Comment: @EstebanP. I am actually querying on instituionId and or userId and it takes longer. I figured the select * would be a start for me to understand

Comment: Any reason why the negative vote??

Comment: Have you looked at your execution plan?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I added the execution plan to the question

Comment: Are you using a stored proc for this select statement or are you creating the select in your web app? Can you show that piece of code you are getting the deadlock on?

Answer (score 2):

You've asked about two different queries.

The more important one seems to be

```
SELECT *
FROM   notifications
WHERE  DisplayDate IS NULL
       AND Fk_userId = [the user id]
```

The execution plan shows that you are missing any useful index so are getting a parallel scan of the whole table.

If you provide an index then it should perform much better and be less deadlock prone simply by virtue of needing to read less data.

An example index for that query would be

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Fk_userId_Where_DisplayDate_Is_Null
  ON notifications(Fk_userId)
  INCLUDE (DisplayDate) 
  WHERE DisplayDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to many reasons:

Maybe someone else is accessing to this table too and locked it. In that case, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Notifications WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Sometimes the problem is related to missing indexes. I don't think it has to do with indexes since you have a primary key. However, you need to check the degree of fragmentation of that index and rebuild it if necessary.

Another key point could be the [query optimization statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql). You can update them by doing this:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS Notifications;
```

As per you last update, you can use this query to deal with blocking:

```
-- Detect blocking (run multiple times)  (Query 62) (Detect Blocking)
SELECT t1.resource_type AS [lock type], DB_NAME(resource_database_id) AS [database],
t1.resource_associated_entity_id AS [blk object],t1.request_mode AS [lock req],  --- lock requested
t1.request_session_id AS [waiter sid], t2.wait_duration_ms AS [wait time],       -- spid of waiter  
(SELECT [text] FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r WITH (NOLOCK)                      -- get sql for waiter
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.[sql_handle]) 
WHERE r.session_id = t1.request_session_id) AS [waiter_batch],
(SELECT SUBSTRING(qt.[text],r.statement_start_offset/2, 
    (CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 
    THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), qt.[text])) * 2 
    ELSE r.statement_end_offset END - r.statement_start_offset)/2) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.[sql_handle]) AS qt
WHERE r.session_id = t1.request_session_id) AS [waiter_stmt],                   -- statement blocked
t2.blocking_session_id AS [blocker sid],                                        -- spid of blocker
(SELECT [text] FROM sys.sysprocesses AS p                                       -- get sql for blocker
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.[sql_handle]) 
WHERE p.spid = t2.blocking_session_id) AS [blocker_stmt]
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
ON t1.lock_owner_address = t2.resource_address OPTION (RECOMPILE);

-- Helps troubleshoot blocking and deadlocking issues
-- The results will change from second to second on a busy system
-- You should run this query multiple times when you see signs of blocking
```

Comment: I agree!

Other reasons for your query to be slow, you are including all the columns and there is no WHERE clause on it. You may think you will get performance benefit since you have a clustered index, but it's not

Comment: @luis Teijon adding `WITH(NOLOCK)` didn't seem to make a change in make case even if it could be an issue since the query on that table return a deadlock application error sometimes (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

You have a text field (NotificationText) in your table. "Text" in SQL Server is a type of BLOB (Binary Large OBject). These Field types are very difficult to optimise. You can use full text indexing but it gets complicated.

I would try a select excluding that field. Or, ask yourself if you really need to use Text. Would Nvarchar(8000) suffice?

I bet if you remove that Text field, or redefine it as an nvarchar, your query will suddenly start flying.

Comment: It could be it... It's going to require some work before i can actually test this. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Good luck! And please consider an upvote or accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: I finally tried your solution and it seems that it made it worse... I could not get nothing but deadlocks on the table compared to before where I would get a deadlock once in a while

Comment: That surprises me. but I think I'll leave this to people who use SQl Server more regularly than I do . . . you seem to have them in the thread.